# Emitting a `Signal` to directly transition a `QStateMachine` to another `QState`

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, qstatemachine

I have the following state machine:

[image]

I have implemented this in Python via the standard state pattern. This state machine is running in a separate thread from a PySide6 application thread, which is running on the program's main thread. Let's call this state machine class `Controller`.

On the GUI side, I am using the [Qt for Python State Machine Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/overviews/statemachine-api.html). (Note: the linked documentation is for PySide2/PySide5, but I am using Pyside6. For some reason, the same documentation doesn't exist for PySide6.) This makes it very nice to define what happens in the GUI when a state is entered.

What I am looking for is *not* for the GUI to initiate transitions but for my core state machine `Controller` running in another thread to control the transitions. Typically, one uses `<QState>.addTransition(...)` to add a transition at the GUI level, but I want the GUI to simple send commands down to `Controller`, and then when `Controller` transitions its state, I want it to emit a `Signal` that triggers the PySide6 `QStateMachine` to enter a given state and thus set all the properties appropriate for that state. So in other words, I want the GUI to dispatch commands to the `Controller` state machine and for the GUI to "listen" for the `Controller`'s state transitions.

---

So the question is, given a `QState`, how do I send a signal to it that forces the `QStateMachine` it is a part of to transition to that state? Or do I need to send a signal to the `QStateMachine` and provide it a `QState` to transition to?

Example program:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import override
from PySide6.QtStateMachine import QState


class Controller:
    def __init__(self, initial_state: IState, states: list[QState]) -> None:
        """Initialize the controller to the given initial state and call the `
        on_entry` method for the state.
        """
        self.__state = initial_state
        self.__state.controller = self
        self.__state.on_entry()
        self.__state.states = states

    def _transition_to(self, new_state: IState) -> None:
        """Transition from the current state to the given new state. This calls
        the `on_exit` method on the current state and the `on_entry` of the
        new state. This method should not be called by any object other than
        concrete implementations of `IState`.
        """
        self.__state.on_exit()
        self.__state = new_state
        self.__state.controller = self
        self.__state.on_entry()

    @property
    def state(self):
        """Get the current state"""
        return self.__state

    def start_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        self.__state.start_camera_exposure()

    def stop_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        self.__state.stop_camera_exposure()

    def abort_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        self.__state.abort_camera_exposure()


class IState(ABC):
    """Serve as an interface between the controller and the explicit, individual states."""

    @property
    def controller(self) -> Controller:
        return self.__controller

    @controller.setter
    def controller(self, controller: Controller) -> None:
        self.__controller = controller

    @property
    def states(self) -> list[QState]:
        return self.__states

    @states.setter
    def states(self, states: list[QState]):
        self.__states = states

    def on_entry(self) -> None:
        """Can be overridden by a state to perform an action when the state is
        being entered, i.e., transitions into. It is not required to be overridden.
        """
        pass

    def on_exit(self) -> None:
        """Can be overridden by a state to perform an action when the state is
        being exited, i.e., transitioned from. It is not required to be overridden.
        """
        pass

    # If a concrete implementation does not handle the called method, i.e., it is an invalid action
    # in the specific state, it is enough to simply call `pass`.

    @abstractmethod
    def start_camera_exposure(self) -> None: ...

    @abstractmethod
    def stop_camera_exposure(self) -> None: ...

    @abstractmethod
    def abort_camera_exposure(self) -> None: ...


class Idle(IState):
    @override
    def on_entry(self):
        # I want to emit a signal here to force a `QStateMachine` to go to state: `self.__states[0]`
        print("Idling ...")

    def start_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        self.controller._transition_to(CameraExposing())

    def stop_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass

    def abort_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass


class CameraExposing(IState):
    @override
    def on_entry(self) -> None:
        # I want to emit a signal here to force a `QStateMachine` to go to state: `self.__states[1]`
        print("Starting camera exposure ...")

    @override
    def on_exit(self) -> None:
        print("Stopping camera exposure ...")

    def start_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass

    def stop_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        self.controller._transition_to(SavingCameraImages())

    def abort_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        self.controller._transition_to(AbortingCameraExposure())


class SavingCameraImages(IState):
    @override
    def on_entry(self) -> None:
        # I want to emit a signal here to force a `QStateMachine` to go to state: `self.__states[2]`
        print("Saving camera images ...")
        self.controller._transition_to(Idle())

    def start_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass

    def stop_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass

    def abort_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass


class AbortingCameraExposure(IState):
    @override
    def on_entry(self) -> None:
        # I want to emit a signal here to force a `QStateMachine` to go to state: `self.__states[3]`
        print("Aborting camera exposure ...")
        self.controller._transition_to(Idle())

    def start_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass

    def stop_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass

    def abort_camera_exposure(self) -> None:
        pass
```

On the GUI side, I have something like:

```py
from PySide6.QtStateMachine import QState, QStateMachine


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.machine = QStateMachine(parent=self)
        self.state_idle = QState(self.machine)
        self.state_camera_exposing = QState(self.machine)
        self.state_saving_camera_images = QState(self.machine)
        self.state_aborting_camera_exposure = QState(self.machine)
        self.machine.setInitialState(self.state_idle)
        self.states = [
            self.state_idle,
            self.state_camera_exposing,
            self.state_saving_camera_images,
            self.state_aborting_camera_exposure,
        ]

        self.initialize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I have so far figured out how to do this is by simply creating adding all possible transitions for every transition signal for every state.

Inside `class MainWindow(QWidget)`, define class variables to represent the various transition signals:

```py
transition_to_idle = Signal()
transition_to_camera_exposing = Signal()
transition_to_saving_camera_images = Signal()
transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure = Signal()
```

Then add transitions for each of these signals for each state, transitioning to the state determined by the signal:

```py
machine = self.machine
state_idle = self.state_idle
state_camera_exposing = self.state_camera_exposing
state_saving_camera_images = self.state_saving_camera_images
state_aborting_camera_exposure = self.state_aborting_camera_exposure

state_idle.addTransition(self.transition_to_idle, state_idle)
state_idle.addTransition(self.transition_to_camera_exposing, state_camera_exposing)
state_idle.addTransition(self.transition_to_saving_camera_images, state_saving_camera_images)
state_idle.addTransition(self.transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure, state_aborting_camera_exposure)

state_camera_exposing.addTransition(self.transition_to_idle, state_idle)
state_camera_exposing.addTransition(self.transition_to_camera_exposing, state_camera_exposing)
state_camera_exposing.addTransition(self.transition_to_saving_camera_images, state_saving_camera_images)
state_camera_exposing.addTransition(self.transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure, state_aborting_camera_exposure)

state_saving_camera_images.addTransition(self.transition_to_idle, state_idle)
state_saving_camera_images.addTransition(self.transition_to_camera_exposing, state_camera_exposing)
state_saving_camera_images.addTransition(self.transition_to_saving_camera_images, state_saving_camera_images)
state_saving_camera_images.addTransition(self.transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure, state_aborting_camera_exposure)

state_aborting_camera_exposure.addTransition(self.transition_to_idle, state_idle)
state_aborting_camera_exposure.addTransition(self.transition_to_camera_exposing, state_camera_exposing)
state_aborting_camera_exposure.addTransition(self.transition_to_saving_camera_images, state_saving_camera_images)
state_aborting_camera_exposure.addTransition(self.transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure, state_aborting_camera_exposure)
```

Then in the other thread, signals are emitted with [`emit`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/Signal.html#PySide6.QtCore.Signal.emit):

```py
transition_to_idle.emit()
transition_to_camera_exposing.emit()
transition_to_saving_camera_images.emit()
transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure.emit()
```

---

**Edit**: To set the transitions more succinctly, a for loop can be used. For example:

```py
for state in states:
    state.addTransition(self.transition_to_idle, state_idle)
    state.addTransition(self.transition_to_camera_exposing, state_camera_exposing)
    state.addTransition(self.transition_to_saving_camera_images, state_saving_camera_images)
    state.addTransition(self.transition_to_aborting_camera_exposure, state_aborting_camera_exposure)
```

where `states` is a list of all the possible states.

Comment: It would still be good to know if there is a way in the Qt for Python State Machine Framework to directly transition a state rather than having to create all these custom signals and add them as transitions for every state. It seems intuitive that there should be a method on the state machine that just says "go to this state now".